# C# can you hide an inherited interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a set of interfaces and classes that look something like this:

```
public interface IItem
{
    // interface members
}
public class Item<T> : IItem
{
    // class members, and IItem implementation
}
public interface IItemCollection : IEnumerable<IItem>
{
    // This should be enumerable over all the IItems
}
// We cannot implement both IItemCollection and IEnumerable<TItem> at
// the same time, so we need a go between class to implement the
// IEnumerable<IItem> interface explicitly:
public abstract class ItemCollectionBase : IItemCollection
{
    protected abstract IEnumerator<IItem> GetItems();
    IEnumerator<IItem> IEnumerable<IItem>.GetEnumerator() { return GetItems(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetItems(); }
}

public class ItemCollection<TKey, TItem> : ItemCollectionBase, IEnumerable<TItem>
    where TItem : class,IItem,new()
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TItem> dictionary;
    protected override GetItems() { return dictionary.Values; }
    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() { return dictionary.Values; }
}
```

The problem I run into is when I try use Linq on my ItemCollection, it gets confused because there are two IEnumerable interfaces.

I get the following error message:

*The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(...) cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Is there any way to hide the "more primitive" IEnumerable<IItem> interface so it will always choose the IEnumerable<TItem> when dealing with the ItemCollection<,>, but still provide the IEnumerable<IItem> interface when dealing with IItemCollection interface?

---

(As I'm about to post this, I realized that there's a workaround, to implement it like this:

```
public interface IItemCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; }
}
```

But I still want to know if there's a way to hide an interface.)

Comment: i'm not 100% but wouldn't fully qualifying the interface name achieve this effect?

Comment: If you specify ((IEnumerable<IItem>)Itemcollection).Where(...), it will work, but that's an extremely painful way to deal with it.

Comment: No, I mean, you make the type fully qualify the interface name when inheriting from it. I'm not posting it as an answer because I'm not sure it will work. `interface IItemCollection : My.Namespace.IEnumerable<IItem>`

Comment: @DanPantry IEnumerable<IItem> doesn't exist in "My.Namespace", only in "System.Collections.Generic".  If you define your own version of IEnumerable<T> in a different namespace, stuff like Linq won't work with it.

Comment: |: I thought you were implementing two IEnumerable types. I get your problem now. I don't think there is a way to achieve what you are doing.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to hide it. Note, that you can always explicitly specify the generic parameter like `Where<IItem>(x => ...)`. However, this pattern is very bad for consumers of your code. You never see it in framework libraries. For example, in EF you have `DbSet<T>` and `DbSet` which you might think inherit from one another, but in fact there is only an implicit conversion from `DbSet<T>` to `DbSet` and a `Cast<T>` method to go in the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could achieve what you want with a little bit of composition instead of inheritance:

```
public interface IItem
{
    // interface members
}
public class Item<T> : IItem
{
    // class members, and IItem implementation
}
public interface IItemCollection
{
    IEnumerable<IItem> GetItems();
}    
public class ItemCollection<TKey, TItem> : IItemCollection, IEnumerable<TItem>
    where TItem : class,IItem,new()
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TItem> dictionary;
    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator() { return dictionary.Values; }
    public IEnumerable<IItem> GetItems() { return dictionary.Values.Cast<IItem>(); }
}
```

We can change `IItemCollection` so that it returns an `IEnumerable<IItem>` instead of implementing `IEnumerable<IItem>`. Now your concrete class can implement *all* interfaces and you don't need abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are heading to a clever design (if there is one) which violates [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able
>   to use objects of derived classes without knowing it.

As someone smarter than me once said "don't make your design clever, KISS."

Comment: Violation of that rule was not part of the goal.  Anyone using the interface should get back IItem, but anyone knowing the full type of the collection can get back the properly typed items (which are also instances of IItem).